# How to return all elements matching field in a List<Foo>?

Tags: c#, linq, list, types

I'm coding a method that should return all records in a List matching an email field. But my current implementation only returns the first element as I'm using the `.FirstOrDefault();`

I filtered through the other methods available using *intellisense* and tried using `ToList();`

```
return orderList.Where(c => c.Email == email).ToList();
```

But I get an error stating that it can't be converted as the result isn't a List. I understand from this that the result isn't of type list, but how can I return a list instead.

> Error 30  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'MongoDBApp.Models.OrderModel'

Anyone know how I can return the complete result set?

This is the method at present which returns only the first or default element matching the email key:

```
public async Task<OrderModel> GetByEmailAsync(string email)
{
    if (orderList == null)
        await LoadDbAsync();
    return orderList.Where(c => c.Email == email).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

And the orderList which is of type, OrderModel:

```
private static List<OrderModel> orderList = new List<OrderModel>();
```

Comment: Change your GetByEmailAsync return type to Task<IEnumerable<OrderModel>>.  The error isn't saying that the result is not a list, it is telling you that it can't convert the list of OrderModels you are returning to a single OrderModel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing your method to this should work

```
public async Task<List<OrderModel>> GetByEmailAsync(string email)
{
    if (orderList == null)
        await LoadDbAsync();
    return orderList
            .Where(c => c.Email == email)
            .ToList();
}
```

With your current implementation `async Task<OrderModel> GetByEmailAsync(string email)`, the method needs to return a single `OrderModel`, so you cannot return a `List<OrderModel>` with `Where(...).ToList()`.